# how to backslash a backslash in zsh bindkey?

Tags: grep, zsh, backslash, bindkey

I would like to replace the key as this:

```
bindkey -s ',;' "| grep -A5 \"^\\s{3,}-\"\ei"
```

in my zshrc, but the `\\s` part (which should be `\s` for space in PCRE), gives something like this:

```
| grep -A5 "^S{3,}-"
```

so there is some garbage instead of `\s`. So how can I achieve the backslash?

Comment: The simplest option would be to use the  POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` instead of the Perl-style class `\s`.

Comment: How about using 4 backslashes? So `\\\\s`

Comment: Also. if you don't need to do substitution in the string, probably use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Update: After some experimentation, you probably need **eight** backslashes if 4 doesn't work: `\\\\\\\\s`  ... this indicates that the string is processed twice: The string encodes 4 backslashes, the first processing reduces that to 2 backslashes, then the second processing reduces that to 1 backslash.

Comment: @pepoluan I have not tried that yet, but it that is true, then it is funny. I mean why is it processed twice in zsh? I do have that in ubuntu, which classic bash, and there is no need for 8 of them, just 2. So what is going on in zsh keybinding?

Comment: @milanHrabos I have no idea. Probably some zsh preprocessing. It is, after all, a different beast from bash. Only maintaining some superficial resemblance, but internally it has so much modifications + advanced substitution features.

Answer (score 1):

While it's *possible* to get the quoting right, it's usually better to avoid such nested quoting in the first place. Add a shell function to your `.zshrc` file first:

```
find_it () {
    grep -A5 '^\s{3,}-'
}
```

Then have your widget insert the function instead.

```
bindkey -s ',;' '| find_it\ei'
```

Comment: this does not work of course, since the expansion inserts the name of the function, not the characters itself

Comment: Yes, that's the point. The binding doesn't execute `grep`, either. This is just a shortcut for entering text. (In fact, the entire binding is just a *fragment* of a command, as a command cannot start with a `|`.)